# A safety concern about clicking a div and then updating mysql database with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm using php to instantiate a number of divs depending on how many folders there are in a directory.
And each such directory has a number of pictures in there and I'm just getting the first one to set as image in the currently instantiated div.

```
<?php
    $dir = "../assets/wallpapers/pc/";
    $themes = array_diff(scandir($dir), array('.', '..'));
    foreach ($themes as $t) { ?>
        <?php 
        $tdir = $dir . $t;
        $imgdir = $tdir . "/" . scandir($tdir)[2];
        ?>
        <div class="div_5" onclick="select_theme('<?=$t;?>');">
            <img src="<?=$imgdir;?>">
            <div><span><?=ucwords($t);?></span></div>
        </div>
<?php } ?>
```

I know it's a bit confusing but my concern is that on the div onclick event, I call a javascript function (select_theme) and as it's parameter I'm passing a php variable $t. The select_theme function basically gets the parameter and sends a ajax post to update the database. My concern is that when I go F12 on the browser I can change the select_theme parameter manually and therefore I'm scared that in that way the person would be able to type anything and the ajax would send whatever string the person wants.... and so on. Is this the proper way to do this?

**SOLVED! Look at Nick's comment.**

Comment: That is always a risk. Any user input should be validated on the server; you cannot rely on client-side validation because - as you have seen - it is easily bypassed.

Comment: But how do I distinguish the divs (by $t) when I don't put the $t in the html itself?

Comment: You do need to put `$t` (or something that translates to it e.g. a uuid) in the html. But on your server you have to check that the value submitted is valid (i.e. one of the legal values of `$t`) and - if required - that the user is allowed to use that value of `$t`.

Comment: Understood. Thank you so much!